# Find $\int \tan(\tan x)\hspace{1mm}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Find $\int \tan(\tan x)\hspace{1mm}dx$

This is an Interesting problem, which I have been trying from different directions, nothing seems to work, its been a day on this one.

Can anyone figure out how to approach it elegantly

Comment: See the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) and [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)).

Answer (score 0):

By using the formula http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/7/2/a/72a1058ad2087aec467af24bddcf9479.png, we have $\int\tan(\tan x)~dx=x\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2^n}\tan\left(\tan\dfrac{mx}{2^n}\right)+C$